# How to change URL params using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

i need to change an image URL size like `https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/2020/463/204/20403402364_1834014696.jpg_50x50.jpg` to
`https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/2020/463/204/20403402364_1834014696.jpg_800x800.jpg`

Actually i need to change all image from api `50*50` to `800*800`, how can i replace URL keyword using javascript or regular expression?

`50*50` to `800*800` is not working using regular expression.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should try to find a solution yourself and if you get stuck post your attempt (relevant code) so the people here can recreate your problem and give you advice on how to fix it. Here is a link with some information on how to improve your Question: [stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/string/replace)

```js
function updateSize(url, size) {
  return url.replace(/_\d+x\d+/, `_${size}x${size}`)
}

const url = 'https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/2020/463/204/20403402364_1834014696.jpg_50x50.jpg'

console.log(updateSize(url, 800))
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be easy

```js
function imageUrl(url, size) {
  var startUrl = url.substr(0, url.indexOf("jpg_"));
  var fullUrl = startUrl + size + "x" + size + ".jpg";
  return fullUrl;

}

console.log(imageUrl("https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/2020/463/204/20403402364_1834014696.jpg_50x50.jpg", 800))
```

Comment: This will only work for `.jpg` images, and if `url` ends with a query string, that information will be trimmed off by this function.

Comment: I gave you an example about how you could do it, i cant think of all the possible scenario. If you are sure about   `50x50` then use repleace instead.

Comment: @Justin Taddei have a perfect solution. I recommend it.